# Javaについて

Tags: java

AはBのオブジェクトを生成してBを返す
Bはレコードを追加する
Cは引数にBのオブジェクトを持ち追加したレコードによってファイルを作成しそのファイル名を返す

AとBはできましたがBで作成したlistをどうやってCに渡すかがわかりません

```
public class A{
    public B create(){
        B b = new B()
        return b;
    }
}
```

Bは

```
public class B{
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    publc void add(int a,int b,String c){
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

としまして
Xでは

```
public class x{
    public void test{
        A a = new A();
        B b = a.create();
        b.add(000001,1234,"テストデータ");
    }
}
```

これで想定の結果が出力されました。
後はCのメソッドを作ってXで呼び出せれば完成です

Cでは

```
public class C{
    public String createFile(B add){
        //ファイルを作成
    }
}
```

このCの部分を作成するに当たってBのaddという情報を渡すにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 「レコードを追加する」というのはデータベーステーブルのレコードですか？

Comment: 実際のコーディングになればデータベースのレコードだと思いますが
今回はスタブなので
Bのメソッドの引数が10個ほどあるのですがこれのひとつひとつをファイル作成用の変数？か何かに追加することだと思っております。

Comment: スタブ化するのはABCの3つですか?スタブを呼び出すクラスはABCをそれぞれどのように使っているか質問に追記できますでしょうか？

Comment: スタブ化するのはABCの3つで間違えないとと思いますが
スタブを呼び出すクラス・・・
こちらは何も定義されていなくて

私が一番わからないのがスタブを呼び出すクラス
これがまず何を呼び出してどのように処理していくかがわからなくて困っております

Comment: お困りのようですね。 スタブを呼び出すクラスを仮にXと書きますが、 コメントを拝見する限り Xがすでに有るか無いかで対応変わってきそうですね。 Xがすでにあるなら X の仕様に合わせて ABC を作る必要がありますね。Xがないのであれば、わかっている範囲の仕様で ABCを設計して X 作成者に提供することになるのではと思います。

Comment: take様
解決いたしました

難しく捕らえすぎてたみたいでして

Aは
public class A{
    public B create(){
        B b = new B()
        return b;
    }
}

Bは
public class B{
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    publc void B add(int a,int b,String c){
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);
        System.out.println(list);
}
としまして
Xでは
public class x{
    public void test{
        A a = new A();
        B b = a.create();
        b.add(000001,1234,"テストデータ");
    }
}
と作ったところXで入力したデータは思ったとおりに出力されました。
後はCを作成するのとXでCを呼び出すだけだと思います。

長文になりまして申し訳ありません
そして大変お世話になりました
ありがとうございました。

Comment: わかりずらいですね

質問に追記します

Comment: @Katsumiさんの回答にある Class Bの`getRecord()`のようにするのでは解決できませんか？

Comment: 解決しました
長い事お付き合いいただきありがとうございました

Answer (score 2):

スタブということなので、レコードの追加処理やファイルの生成処理の実コード的な部分ではなく、クラスの輪郭を作る方法がわからないという解釈で説明します。

Javaのクラスはインスタンス化しないと使えません。ですので、A,B,Cのクラスを使うには下記のようにそれぞれインスタンス化する必要があります。

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
```

また、クラスに何かをさせるにはクラスにメソッドを定義する必要があります。

- Aのクラスは「Bのオブジェクトを生成する」メソッドが必要
- Bのクラスは「レコードを追加する」メソッドと、Cクラスがファイルを作る際に呼ぶ「レコードを取得する」メソッドが必要
- Cのクラスは「ファイルを生成してファイル名を返す」メソッドが必要

これらを踏まえると、A,B,Cのクラス定義は下記のようになるかと思います。

クラスA:

```
public class A
{
    /** Bオブジェクトを生成する */
    public void createB()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

クラスB:

```
public class B
{
    /** レコードを追加する */
    public void addRecord(Object object)
    {
    }

    /** レコードを取得する */
    public Object getRecord()
    {
    }
}
```

クラスC:

```
public class C
{
    public String createFile(B b)
    {
        // 作成したレコードを取得
        Object object = b.getRecord();
        // ファイルを作成する処理
        ・・・
        return "ファイル名";
    }
}
```

これらを利用する場合は下記のようになります。

```
A a = new A();
// Bオブジェクトの生成
B b = a.createB();
// レコードの追加
b.addRecord(/* レコード情報を表す何か */);
// ファイル生成
C c = new C();
String fileName = c.createFile(b);
```

インプットとなる情報が何であるのかは提示されていないため引数は適当に記載しています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます

えと、一応クラスの作り方や輪郭はわかってるのですが
上のコメントで書いたとおり

ABCのどれかを呼び出すクラスがありそこからどう処理をしていくと最終的にCのファイルを返せるかという処理の流れが一番わからないのです

言葉足らずで申し訳ございません